# Как передавать стринговский массив через socket builder c++?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Нужно передавать массив из 100 элементов состоящий из двух символов

```
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            #include <vcl.h>
            #pragma hdrstop

            #include "main.h"
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #pragma package(smart_init)
            #pragma resource "*.dfm"
            TFormMain *FormMain;
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            __fastcall TFormMain::TFormMain(TComponent* Owner)
                    : TForm(Owner)
            {
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void TFormMain::SendingMessages(AnsiString Message) //Функция рассылки сообщений
            {
                   MemoMessages->Lines->Add(Message); //Вывод сообщения на экран
                   for(int i = 0; i < ServerSocket->Socket->ActiveConnections; i++) //Цикл перебирает всех подключенных
                   {
                            ServerSocket->Socket->Connections[i]->SendText(Message); //Рассылка сообщений
                   }
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonStartClick(TObject *Sender) //Кнопка запуска сервера
            {
                    EditPort->Enabled    = false; //Отключаем поле ввода порта
                    ButtonStart->Enabled = false; //Отключаем кнопку запуска
                    ServerSocket->Port = EditPort->Text.ToInt(); //Заем серверу порт
                    ServerSocket->Active = true; //Включаем сервер
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void __fastcall TFormMain::ServerSocketClientRead(TObject *Sender,
                  TCustomWinSocket *Socket) //Обработчик читающий сообщения
            {
                    SendingMessages(Socket->ReceiveText()); //Читаем сообщния и рассылаем их через функцию SendingMessages()
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------


            void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonSendClick(TObject *Sender) //Кнопка отслыки сообщения
            {
                   SendingMessages("Сервер: " + EditMessage->Text); //Рассылаем сообщение через функцию SendingMessages()
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            void __fastcall TFormMain::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action) //Обработчик закрытия формы
            {
                    ServerSocket->Active = false; //При закрытии формы отключаем сервер       
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Т.е. каждый символ - это 50 элементов? :) Вы как-то понятнее задачи ставьте...

Comment: Имеется ввиду размерность массива 100 элементов, а каждый элемент предоставляет собой два символа

Comment: Вы бы написали хоть какие классы используете, привели бы ссылки на документацию, указали версию билдера, может быть код Ваших попыток привели и т.д.

Comment: builder версии 6, код копипастнул но по такому же принципу